# MYSQL which column for a row has the highest value

Tags: mysql

so I have a table like this in MYSQL

```
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| Names   | MAP1 | MAP2 | MAP3 | MAP4 |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| Player1 | 2    | 3    | 1    | 4    |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| Player2 | 1    | 4    | 3    | 2    |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
| Player4 | 3    | 2    | 1    | 1    |
+---------+------+------+------+------+
```

How would I go about selecting which map a player has the most on. So something like this

```
+---------+------+
| Names   | MAPS |
+---------+------+
| Player1 | MAP1 |
+---------+------+
| Player2 | MAP2 |
+---------+------+
| Player4 | MAP1 |
+---------+------+
```

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor schema design.

Comment: For Player1 the expected result should be MAP4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your schema. A normalised design might look somewhat as follows, wherein `names` and `map` would be components of a PRIMARY KEY:

```
+---------+-----+-----+
| Names   | MAP | VAL |
+---------+-----+-----+
| Player1 |   1 |   2 |
| Player2 |   2 |   1 |
| Player4 |   3 |   3 |
| Player1 |   1 |   3 |
| Player2 |   2 |   4 |
| Player4 |   3 |   2 |
| Player1 |   1 |   1 |
| Player2 |   2 |   3 |
| Player4 |   3 |   1 |
| Player1 |   1 |   4 |
| Player2 |   2 |   2 |
| Player4 |   3 |   1 |
+---------+-----+-----+
```

From here, the problem is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Strawberry is correct - you are hobbled by a very bad schema design.

There are various ways of achieving this with your current schema but they are *all* ugly hacks:

```
 DELIMITER $$
 CREATE FUNCTION maxmap(map1 INT, map2 INT, map3 INT, map4 INT)
 RETURNS TEXT
 BEGIN
   DECLARE maxmapt TEXT;
   DECLARE maxmapv INT;
   SET maxmapt = 'map1';
   SET maxmapv = map1 ;
   IF (map2 > map1) THEN
      SET maxmapt = 'map2';
      SET maxmapv = map2 ;
   END IF;
   IF (map3 > maxmapv) THEN
      SET maxmapt = 'map3';
      SET maxmapv = map3 ;
   END IF;
   IF (map4 > maxmapv) THEN
      SET maxmapt = 'map4';
   END IF;
   RETURN maxmapt;
 END;
 $$
 SELECT player, maxmap
 FROM yourtable
 $$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `greatest()` in a `CASE` expression:

```
select Names,
  case greatest(MAP1, MAP2, MAP3, MAP4)
    when MAP1 then 'MAP1'
    when MAP2 then 'MAP2'
    when MAP3 then 'MAP3'
    when MAP4 then 'MAP4'
  end MAPS
from tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nHHK4i2uFF7Hrd34fc6QPC/0).
Results:

```
| Names   | MAPS |
| ------- | ---- |
| Player1 | MAP4 |
| Player2 | MAP2 |
| Player4 | MAP1 |
```

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cW25KY8Gzb5ficSpxVebvM/0

Comment: This seems to answer the question that was asked. OP did not specify how ties should be handled.